# jQuery ui tab table structure

Tags: jquery

I have 2 tabs in my application, where each tab displays datatable from the server. When i click on the second tab it displays only the data of the table with out styles and even search box also.

here is my view...

- Un-Published Deals
- Published Deals
- index.php/settings/providerdeal/index"> Create Deal

S.No.
                     Deal Title                   
                       Deal Type 
                      Start Date
                    End Date
                      Status
                      Actions
                
            
            
        

    
    
        
            
                
                    S.No.
                     Deal Title                   
                       Deal Type 
                      Start Date
                    End Date
                      Status
                      Actions

and js................
//Read records start
    function readUsers() {

```
    //display ajax loader animation
    $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeIn('slow');

    $.ajax({
        url: readUrl,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            for (var i in response) {
                response[ i ].serial_number = parseInt(i) + 1;
                response[ i ].updateLink = updateUrl + '/' + response[ i ].deal_id;
                response[ i ].deleteLink = delUrl + '/' + response[ i ].deal_id;
            }

            //clear old rows
            $('#records > tbody').html('');

            //append new rows
            $('#readTemplate').render(response).appendTo("#records > tbody");

            //apply dataTable to #records table and save its object in dataTable variable
            if (typeof dataTable == 'undefined')
                dataTable = $('#records').dataTable({
                    "bJQueryUI": true
                });

            //hide ajax loader animation here...
            $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
} // end readUsers
//Read records end



function preadUsers() {

    //display ajax loader animation
    $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeIn('slow');

    $.ajax({
        url: readUrl1,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response) {
            for (var i in response) {
                response[ i ].serial_number = parseInt(i) + 1;
                response[ i ].updateLink = updateUrl + '/' + response[ i ].deal_id;
                response[ i ].deleteLink = delUrl + '/' + response[ i ].deal_id;
            }

            //clear old rows
            $('#precords > tbody').html('');

            //append new rows
            $('#preadTemplate').render(response).appendTo("#precords > tbody");

            //apply dataTable to #precords table and save its object in dataTable variable
            if (typeof dataTable == 'undefined')
                dataTable = $('#precords').dataTable({
                   "bJQueryUI": true
                });

            //hide ajax loader animation here...
            $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
} // end readUsers
//Read records end
```

Comment: search for errors in the debugger/console. You might have JQuery errors.

Comment: How can we do this from a scratch ??? lol... Please show the code in jsfiddle @user2814660

Comment: this is the my view..........

Comment: How you cretaed the tab??@user2814660